# Kiwi TCMS under Docker windows issues

Tags: docker, kiwi-tcms

Below is my configuration:

- Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962
- Host OS: Win 10 Pro

I am evaluating this tool for my personal use. But the problem is that some of my standard port is already in use either by IIS/System on the host. I was able to get the kiwi docker image and also clone the GIT repo.

Since the standard ports are already in use, I changed the docker-compose.yml file as shown below:

```
ports:
        - 90:8080
        - 1443:8443
```

Now the docker container kiwi_web is up and running successfully on 1443 port. But it displays *Internal Server Error* when I visit the page. I guess this error is because more commands to be executed?

As per the documentation, now I am trying to execute the next command, which results in an error.

```
    $ winpty docker exec -it kiwi_web /Kiwi/manage.py migrate
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"C:/Program Files/Git/Kiwi/manage.py\": stat C:/Program Files/Git/Kiwi/manag
e.py: no such file or directory": unknown
```

What should I do? Yes, I am executing this command from the cloned repository directory.

Are there better instructions to do this activity on Windows machines?

UPDATE:
I managed to find the OIC problem issue. Below is the changed command:

```
$ winpty docker exec -it kiwi_web //bin//sh
sh-4.2$ ls
Kiwi               bin   dev  home              lib    media  opt   root  sbin  sys  usr  venv
anaconda-post.log  boot  etc  httpd-foreground  lib64  mnt    proc  run   srv   tmp  var
sh-4.2$ cd Kiwi/
sh-4.2$ ls
kiwitcms-6.5.3.tar.gz  manage.py  node_modules  package.json  requirements  ssl  static  uploads
sh-4.2$ manage.py migrate
sh: manage.py: command not found
sh-4.2$ ./manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, attachments, auth, contenttypes, core, django_comments, kiwi_auth, linkreference, manag
ement, sessions, sites, testcases, testplans, testruns
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
  Applying attachments.0001_initial... OK
  Applying attachments.0002_auto_20180104_1247... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
  Applying sites.0001_initial... OK
  Applying core.0001_squashed... OK
  Applying django_comments.0001_initial... OK
  Applying django_comments.0002_update_user_email_field_length... OK
  Applying django_comments.0003_add_submit_date_index... OK
  Applying kiwi_auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying management.0003_squashed... OK
  Applying testplans.0005_squashed... OK
  Applying testcases.0001_initial... OK
  Applying testruns.0004_squashed... OK
  Applying linkreference.0001_squashed... OK
  Applying management.0004_remove_sortkey_description... OK
  Applying management.0005_order_by_name... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
  Applying sites.0002_alter_domain_unique... OK
  Applying testcases.0004_squashed... OK
  Applying testcases.0005_remove_unused_fields... OK
  Applying testcases.0006_merge_text_field_into_testcase_model... OK
  Applying testcases.0007_convert_is_automated_to_boolean... OK
  Applying testcases.0008_notifications_default_true... OK
  Applying testplans.0006_remove_testplan_owner... OK
  Applying testplans.0007_notifications_default_true... OK
  Applying testruns.0005_remove_unused_fields... OK
sh-4.2$
```

Looks like I managed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this one https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi/issues/231 and there isn't anything we can do about it. This is a cryptic error comming from your docker installation so your best bet is to google about it. We've seen this kind of error when trying to mount files instead of directories but there could be other things causing it.